# how reverse proxy load balancer managed ssl

Tags: ssl, mod-proxy-balancer

I have the reverse proxy load balancer and its working fine. now want to run this with ssl so how to managed the SSL certs on the backend servers ??

Means what could be the ssl entry/ssl certs for the backedn servers??

Comment: What you are talking about is ssl termination. It should be done at load balancer. But the question is off-topic here.

Comment: means if we mention ssl certs file in load balancer's ssl.conf file no need put else where in background server's ssl.conf ???